# Wrapping Python's io.open Function

Tags: python, io

as you might know, file-streams created by Python's `io.open` function in non-binary mode (e.g. `io.open("myFile.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8"`) do not accept non-`unicode` strings. For a reason that is kind of hard to explain, I want to sort of monkey-patch the `write`-method of those file-streams in order to convert the `string` to be written into a `unicode` before calling the actual `write`-method. My code currently looks like this:

```
import io
import types

def write(self, text):
    if not isinstance(text, unicode):
        text = unicode(text)
    return super(self.__class__, self).write(text)

def wopen(*args, **kwargs):
    f = io.open(*args, **kwargs)
    f.write = types.MethodType(write, f)
    return f
```

However, it does not work:

```
>>> with wopen(p, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
>>>    f.write("test")
UnsupportedOperation: write
```

Since I can not really look into those `built-in`-methods, I have no idea how to analyse the problem.

Thanks in advance!